# Getting server port and contextPath programmatically - springboot

Tags: rest, spring-boot

How can i get the server port and contextPath at runtime?

In application.yml, i am setting these values:

```
server:
    port: 9300
    contextPath: '/apis'
```

In the code, i am building a JSONAPI response to include a reference back to the REST API and therefore the need to programmatically get

```
{
  "relationships": {
    "company": {
      "links": {
        "related": "/api/v1/users/1/company"
      }
    },
    "pets": {
      "links": {
        "related": "/api/v1/users/1/pets"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Example,

```
String related = port? + contextPath? + "/users" + userId + "company";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Inject Spring Boot properties

You can inject the values in your code this way:

```
@Value("${server.port}")
private int port;

@Value("${server.contextPath}")
private String contextPath;
```

### Hateoas

Alternatively, you could take a look at the Hateoas project, which can generate the link section for you: http://docs.spring.io/spring-hateoas/docs/current/reference/html

Answer (score 3):

The following is taken from http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html:

> Spring Boot allows you to externalize your configuration so you can
>   work with the same application code in different environments. You can
>   use properties files, YAML files, environment variables and
>   command-line arguments to externalize configuration. Property values
>   can be injected directly into your beans using the `@Value`
>   annotation, accessed via Spring’s Environment abstraction or bound to
>   structured objects via `@ConfigurationProperties`.
>
> Spring Boot uses a very particular PropertySource order that is
>   designed to allow sensible overriding of values. Properties are
>   considered in the following order:
>
> 1. Devtools global settings properties on your home directory 
>      (~/.spring-boot-devtools.properties when devtools is active).
> 2. @TestPropertySource annotations on your tests.
> 3. @SpringBootTest#properties annotation attribute on your tests.
> 4. Command line arguments.
> 5. Properties from SPRING_APPLICATION_JSON (inline JSON embedded in an
>      environment variable or system property)
> 6. ServletConfig init parameters.
> 7. ServletContext init parameters.
> 8. JNDI attributes from java:comp/env.
> 9. Java System properties (System.getProperties()).
> 10. OS environment variables.
> 11. A RandomValuePropertySource that only has properties in random.*.
> 12. Profile-specific application properties outside of your packaged
>        jar (application-{profile}.properties and YAML variants)
> 13. Profile-specific application properties packaged inside your jar
>        (application-{profile}.properties and YAML variants)
> 14. Application properties outside of your packaged jar
>        (application.properties and YAML variants).
> 15. Application properties packaged inside your jar
>        (application.properties and YAML variants).
> 16. @PropertySource annotations on your @Configuration classes.
> 17. Default properties (specified using
>        SpringApplication.setDefaultProperties).
>
> To provide a concrete example, suppose you develop a @Component that
>   uses a name property:
>
> ```
> import org.springframework.stereotype.*
> import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.*
>
> @Component
> public class MyBean {
>
>     @Value("${name}")
>     private String name;
>
>     // ...
>
> }
> ```
>
> On your application classpath (e.g. inside your jar) you can have an
>   application.properties that provides a sensible default property value
>   for name.  When running in a new environment, an
>   application.properties can be provided outside of your jar that
>   overrides the name; and for one-off testing, you can launch with a
>   specific command line switch (e.g. java -jar app.jar --name="Spring").
>
> [Tip] The SPRING_APPLICATION_JSON properties can be supplied on the
>   command line with an environment variable.  For example in a UN*X
>   shell:
>
> ```
> $ SPRING_APPLICATION_JSON='{"foo":{"bar":"spam"}}' java -jar myapp.jar
> ```
>
> In this example you will end up with foo.bar=spam in the Spring
>   Environment.  You can also supply the JSON as spring.application.json
>   in a System variable:
>
> ```
> $ java -Dspring.application.json='{"foo":"bar"}' -jar myapp.jar
> ```
>
> or command line argument:
>
> ```
> $ java -jar myapp.jar --spring.application.json='{"foo":"bar"}'
> ```
>
> or as a JNDI variable `java:comp/env/spring.application.json.`

Answer (score 1):

Use `@Value` annotation to inject the properties into member variables of your class. You can do this:

```
@Component
public class Foo
{
    @Value("${server.port}")
    String serverPort;

    @Value("${server.contextPath}")
    String contextPath;

    public void doSomething()
    {
            String str = "serverPort: " + serverPort + "; contextPath: " + contextPath;
    }
}
```